# ¿Se puede armar una base de datos en FIREBASE desde java ANDROID STUDIO?

Tags: java, android, json, firebase

Ya sé como hacer mis bloques en la base datos "User" desde el telefono, utilizo esta clase `

```java
public class Users {

    //Declaramos nuestras variables en la base de datos
    private String emeil;
    private String name;
    private String pass;
    private Double dinero;
    private Double percent;
    private Double accion;



    //Esta es necesaria si o si
    public Users(){

    }

    public Users(String emeil, String name, String pass, Double dinero, Double percent, Double accion) {
        this.emeil = emeil;
        this.name = name;
        this.pass = pass;
        this.dinero = dinero;
        this.percent = percent;
        this.accion = accion;
    }

    public String getEmeil() {
        return emeil;
    }

    public void setEmeil(String emeil) {
        this.emeil = emeil;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPass() {
        return pass;
    }

    public void setPass(String pass) {
        this.pass = pass;
    }

    public Double getDinero() {
        return dinero;
    }

    public void setDinero(Double dinero) {
        this.dinero = dinero;
    }

    public Double getPercent() {
        return percent;
    }

    public void setPercent(Double percent) {
        this.percent = percent;
    }

    public Double getAccion() {
        return accion;
    }

    public void setAccion(Double accion) {
        this.accion = accion;
    }
}
` `public class Registro extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText edT_email, edT_name, edT_pass;

    private    Button btn_registrar;
    private String email, name, pass, total="1";
    private double dinero=0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registro);

        iniciar();

        btn_registrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                email=edT_email.getText().toString();
                name=edT_name.getText().toString();
                pass=edT_pass.getText().toString();


                //Verificacion de datos correctos
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(email)&&!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)&&!TextUtils.isEmpty(pass)) {
                    if (pass.length()<6||pass.length()>=11){
                        Toast.makeText(Registro.this, "ERROR, se recomienda una contraseña que sea de 6-10 digitos.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else {
                        if (validarEmailSimplePro(email)==false){
                            Toast.makeText(Registro.this, "ERROR, se recomienda un email con @", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        else {
                            if (name.length()>20||name.length()<4){
                                Toast.makeText(Registro.this, "ERROR, se recomienda un nombre de 4-20 caracteres", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            else {
                                //Si alles sale bien
                                //Conectamos con base
                                DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User");//Nuestra ruta de base
                                //Mandamos el contenido en los edt
                                Users datos=new Users(email, name, pass, dinero, 0.0, 0.0);

                                reference.push().setValue(datos);//Da la KEY y utilizamos nuestra clase de datos

                                Toast.makeText(Registro.this, "Registrado Exitosamente!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(Registro.this, "ERROR DATOS VACIOS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

        });

    }


    private void iniciar(){
        edT_email=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_email_re);
        edT_name=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_Name_res);
        edT_pass=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_pass_re);
        btn_registrar=(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRegistrar_log);
    }

    public static boolean validarEmailSimplePro(String email){

        String regex = "^[A-Za-z0-9+_.-]+@(.+)$";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);

        return matcher.matches();
    }
}
```

que me inserta los datos de la base normal (imagen de abajo)

[image: Base de datos normal]

Pero quiero saber si puedo desde el mismo telefono, crear el bloque de datos que ya se hacer (accion, dinero, email, name, pass,etc) y además otro como nodo, una idea más o menos como en esta imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de obtener el resultado de hasta abajo, directamente en java ANDROID STUDIO

Answer (score 0):

Si, puedes crear esa estructura y con un for podes recorrer cada nodo obteniendo todos sus resultados, cuando uses [getKey()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data?hl=es-419) vas a poder obtener el padre que encierra a los valores `001` y `002`.

Podes crear tanto la base de datos desde android con java como lo venis haciendo, solo deberias añadir un `.child()` mas a la rama, o tambien podes crearla desde la consola en la web.